# Google map API 3 . Container div does not fill fully

Tags: google-maps

I have next problem: There is jquery accordion control. One of tab have div which contains google map. And map does not fill all div. If replace map div out of accordion all work coorectly. How i can fill all div ?
Thanks.

[Like this http://designer4you.ru/pic.jpg](http://designer4you.ru/pic.jpg)

Comment: I had the same issue. Maybe it's a bit late but I proposed a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12477031/1052650).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the discussion here: http://www.mail-archive.com/google-maps-api@googlegroups.com/msg59946.html

Comment: SOPA blackouts ftl. :( - cant see the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```