# Add a function to slidetoggle just when open

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Hi I just make a div that shows a Map on Google, where you set cordinates etc, anyway first problem was when animating height, the map inside have this problem on size :

[how to deal with google map inside of a hidden div (Updated picture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064275/how-to-deal-with-google-map-inside-of-a-hidden-div-updated-picture)

I fix it just like the first answer calling `initialize();` in my slideToggle this fix the size issue.. The problem is that initialize(); takes the same time as the slideToggle so i lose the height animation, it just dissapear,

IS there anyway to tigger `initialize();` just when slidetoggle Open the div?

```
<script>
$('.dropdownmap').click(function(){
    $('#mapDisplayWrap').slideToggle();
    initialize();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [**slideToggle**](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) accept a function callback when the animation is complete.

> .slideToggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )

Try this:

```
$('.dropdownmap').click(function(){
    $('#mapDisplayWrap').slideToggle(400,function(){initialize();});

})
```

if you want it to run just when toggle is open use this:

```
$('.dropdownmap').click(function () {
    $('#mapDisplayWrap').slideToggle(400, function () {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            initialize();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

> IS there anyway to tigger initialize(); just when slidetoggle Open the div?

You'll want to use an animation callback that checks to see if the element is visible (just opened) and execute `initialize` if so.

```
$('.dropdownmap').click(function(){
  $('#mapDisplayWrap').slideToggle(function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible'))
      initialize();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers this is awesome XD!

Comment: Congrats on 10K! +1 to you

Comment: @Sergio Ha! Thanks for noticing. +1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `initialize` as slideToggle callback:

```
$('#mapDisplayWrap').slideToggle(initialize);
```