# How to embed google map using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add a map into "map & direction" of my contact page. i am trying google map embed procedure step by step but it didn't work the is i can't view the map. i am using bootstrap.

Here is my mark up:

```
    <head>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js&output=embed"></script>
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(45.992261, -123.925014);
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myCenter
        });

        function initialize() {
          var mapProp = {
              center:myCenter,
              zoom: 14,
              draggable: false,
              scrollwheel: false,
              mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
          marker.setMap(map);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

          }); 
        };

        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            initialize();
        });

    });
    </script>
   <style type="text/css">
        #map-canvas {
            height:500px;
         }
    </style>
  <head>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="map">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h4 class="h4">Find Us at Google Map</h4>               
            </div>
            <div id="map-canvas" class="col-md-7">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Place both scripts inside your HEAD tag. Be sure to define a width & height of your map-container in the CSS.

Comment: (Re-)initialize the map in a handler for the `shown.bs.tab` event.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/6879644/3342739

Comment: @cvrebert I also follow your link try to show map but it didn't work

Answer (score 6):

Kudos to @ymakux comment "It's better to use built-in classes   " I have been trawling SO for ages looking to get a Google Map to neatly fit into a bootstrap div and your answer is perfect!
So for a newbie like me using maps with Bopotstrap utilizing the sample code supplied by google at  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Add divs as suggested by @ymakux just prior to map div similar to this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
<div id="map-container" class="embed-responsive-item">
<div id="map">
</div>
</div> 
</div>`
```

Comment: Thanks - fixed now but @ymakux needs the credit - his comment was my savior yet hidden like the proverbial needle in a haystack in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

**Try this code its working fine for bootstrap**

```js
function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.1823294, -82.352912),
                zoom: 9,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                scrollwheel: false,
                draggable: false,
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                streetViewControl: true,
                overviewMapControl: true,
                rotateControl: true,
            };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#contactform .btn:hover {
  background: rgba(9,8,77,0.7);
}

#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    
<!--Google Maps API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDnycWatbGyK6ldFqErjFtko1yeMclNUOA&amp;sensor=true"></script>
```

**Please use correct API for google map, You get it from google map console.**

Answer (score -1):

Your bootstrap elements are preventing your map from displaying.

```
<div>        
  <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
      <h4 class="h4">Find Us at Google Map</h4>               
  </div>
  <div id="map-container">
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  </div>     
</div>
```

A little CSS

```
#map-container{
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Your map will display with that.

I would also not place your map calls in your HEAD tag. Let the page load, then have the maps load.

Once you get your map showing, slowly add in bootstrap components, as they can do some weird things with Google maps. Especially with grid layout. If you leave the grid layout on and you can not see the map, resize your browser (clicking the corner and dragging it) and you should be able to hit the sweet spot to display the map.

Comment: It's better to use built-in classes  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <div id="map-container" class="embed-responsive-item"></div>
</div>