# Google Map not showing properly in bootstrap tab

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am working on laravel framework with bootstrap 3 . I want to render my google map in bootstrap tab. but the map is not showing properly. small map show in tab with inline style with gray background. I am adding style on map div but it will not show according to height and width.

kindly advise me any solution.

My issue is resolved by this code:-

```
$('a[href="#tab-4"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                ops2.initGoogleMapCanvas(); 
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064275/how-to-deal-with-google-map-inside-of-a-hidden-div-updated-picture

Answer (score 0):

if this is styling problem check your  and classes

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                 <div class="img-responsive events-map" style="height: 467px;" id="home-event-map"></div>
           </div> 
        </div>
```